# Shorthand way to ToList an awaited method call

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

Is there a way to shorthand or clean up the process of awaiting a method, and tolisting the result that doesn't involve a second new line of code? e.g.

```
var someResult = (await SomeMethodCall(someParameter)).ToList()
```

Or is the best practice to return a list from SomeMethodCall when using await?

Comment: What is wrong with your code? It works fine, right?

Comment: var someResult = SomeMethodCall(someParameter).Result.ToList(). If I understand your question right

Comment: @OlegI Don't do that.

Comment: @PatrickHofman explain?

Comment: @OlegI that will execute immediately and not run asynchronously, so there's no point in using async at all if you do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of two ways of doing that.
If you can modify the `SomeMethod`, just include `.ToList()` to its result and change its return type.

```
var someResult = (await SomeMethodCall(someParameter));
```

Otherwise I would apply the Decorator Pattern and create a new method

```
public List<OldReturnType> SomeMethodAsList(someParameter)
{
    return SomeMethod(someParameter).ToList();
}
```

And then call the new method asynchronously:

```
var someResult = (await SomeMethodAsList(someParameter))
```

Comment: Thank you for the rational answer :). I've kind of come to the same conclusions myself. I guess with async returning Lists is the norm, whereas without async returning IEnumerable was.